# Angular4: Http -> HttpClient - requestOptions

Tags: angular, httpclient

So, I am trying to migrate from 'old' http to the new httpClient

with the http client I am using this format in my service:

```
return this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions)
```

how do I use this in httpClient?

tried many thiungs... including

```
return this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', {params: requestOptions.params})
```

but getting a type missmatch :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
const requestOptions = {
  params: new HttpParams()
};

requestOptions.params.set('foo', 'bar');

this.http.get(environment.api+ '.feed.json', requestOptions );
```

Here is also the link to the docs describing how to do that with examples for headers and URL Parameters: [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers)

Comment: so I cannot use const requestOptions = new RequestOptions(); anymore?

Comment: no, RequestOptions is part of the @angular/http package - see [here](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

Comment: the HttpParams() are really weird.... you cannot do like you did @AndreiMatracaru :/ you have to concatenate like new HttpParams().set('foo', 'bar') otherwise is not working.... and I don't know how to use it if I have many params I need to add but validate first :/

Comment: @DS_web_developer, in case if you have to do some things with your params and add them after this, you can do something like that: `let params = new HttpParams(); params = params.append('foo', 'bar').append('baz', 'qux');` And so on.

Comment: How might I use your example to set `withCredentials: true`?

Comment: I defined an interface for `RequestOptions` in my app based on what Angular expects from the `options` param. Not sure it's a good solution, if not, it will probably get downvoted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977325/angular-httpclient-replacement-for-requestoptions/56977662#56977662