# Angular : Using the equivalent of RequestOptions of Http with HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http, angular-httpclient

i'm migrating from **Http** to **HttpClient**
I'm used to add some **headers** to my http requests like the following with  :

```
import { RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, Headers } from '@angular/http';


this.pass = btoa(cuid + ': ');
this.pass = "Basic " + this.pass;
this.header = new Headers();
this.header.set("Authorization", this.pass);
let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: this.header
});

return this.http.post(myServiceUrl, {}, options)
```

Now when migrating to httpClient , i ve tried this :

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

    const header = new HttpHeaders();
    const pass = 'Basic ' + btoa(cuid + ': ');
    header.set('Authorization', pass);
    const options =  ({
      headers: header
    });
    return this.httpClient.post(myServiceUrl, {}, options);
```

but as you can see ivent find the equivalent of **RequestOptions** , and the whole treatment failed to add the same headers.

**Suggestions??**

Comment: `HttpParams` is the new version, imported from the same place

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `HttpClient.post` method has the following signature:

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: OptionsType)
```

Where the `OptionsType` is the following (equivalent to `RequestOptions`)

```
{
  headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[] };
  observe?: "body";
  params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[] };
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  responseType: "arraybuffer";
  withCredentials?: boolean;
};
```

From there you can assign you header or params, like:

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().append('key', 'value'),
  params: new HttpParams().append('key', 'value')
}


this.httpClient.post(url, {}, options)
```

You could also take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797513/angular4-http-httpclient-requestoptions)

Answer (score 3):

According to https://angular.io/guide/deprecations `RequestOptions` was replaced by `HttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

The http client equivalent should be:

```
const headers = new HttpParams().set('Authorization', pass);
return this.httpClient.post(myServiceUrl, {}, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpParams' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by making a method in my service of `getHeaders(token)`:

```
  getHeaders(token) {
    return new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
  }
```

Then when making requests just append this to the request like so:

`this.http.post(url, body, this.getHeaders(token));`

There is also the HttpInterceptor to look into that can automate this for requests, here is an article for this: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-handling-refresh-token-with-new-httpinterceptor/

I have done this using Firebase Auth for my tokens like this. 
Here is the token.interceptor.ts file:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  afAuth: any;

  constructor(
    private inj: Injector
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.afAuth = this.inj.get(AngularFireAuth);

    return this.getToken().pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }

  getToken() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken());
  }
}
```

Then you need to provide this to your top level app.module like so:

`{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }`

What this does here is set the Authorization token for every HTTP request that gets handled automatically so you do not have to await a token before making requests. Keep in mind this is very specific to Firebase Auth as that's what is giving me the JWT token. Hope this can be of help!