# Using HttpClient and RXJS to POST data to Web API withCredentials: true

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, rxjs, httpclient

I’ve got an `Angular` service that I’ve connected to my `.NET Web API`, and I’m trying to `POST` some data to the API. Currently I'm using `HTTP` rather than `HttpClient`, and I'm not sending any data. But the service is successfully connecting to the API.

I need help with passing actual data through from my Angular controller to the service (and thus to the API), and also implementing `HttpClient` in the service. So far my controller just calls my service's `myFunction()` function and doesn’t pass it any parameters, thus no data. I’m unsure where in the `RXJS` portion of the service to append my data.

**Note: however I implement this, I still need it to pass `withCredentials: true`, due to to the configuration of my API**

**Web API Controller:**

```
namespace api.controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
     {
        static List<string> strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "value0", "value1", "value2"
        };

        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return strings;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            strings.Add(value);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

**Web API web.config file (CORS settings):**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:5200" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**myComponent.component.ts:**

```
  myService: MyService;

  constructor(myService: MyService) {
      this.myService = myService;
      this.myService.myFunction();
   }
```

**myService.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';
// import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyService {
  http: Http;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  };

  public myFunction() {
    let request = new Request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:9090/api/values",
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return this.http.request(request)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .subscribe(
        data => console.warn(data),
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log("empty")
      );
  }
}
```

How might I append some actual data to this service from my controller? And how might I tweak the service to use HttpClient instead? I've tried changing all the `http: Http` references to `HttpClient`, done all the `HttpClient` imports and commented out the `.map/json portions` but I still get a red line under the `request` argument in the line `return this.http.request(request)` of my service when I do so.

Answer (score 4):

I use this concept hope it will work out with you too.

Create property class for your Data (Match it with your class on your .net API), this also provide easy data handling
Model

```
export class MyData
{
 username:string;
 password:string;
 isAuthenticated:boolean;
}
```

service

```
import { Http, Response, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';

export class MyService {     

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

public myFunction(body:MyData) {
 let url = 'http://localhost:9090/api/values'
    return this.http.post(url,body)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))          
  }
}
```

TS

```
returnValue:any;
myData:MyData;
constructor(private service:MyService){
this.myData = new MyData();
}
myFunction()
{
 this.myData.username = 'anything';
 this.myData.password = 'mypw';
 this.myData.isAuthenticated = true;

 this.returnValue = this.service.myFunction(this.myData)
 .subscribe(res=>{console.log(res)})
}
```

.NET API

```
[HttpPost]
public void MYAPI([FromBody]MyData model)
{

    string uname = model.username;
    string pw = model.password;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  You'll notice in my example I passed the `withCredentials: true` key/value pair to `myFunction` within the service. This is something I must have, due to my API configuration. How can I include `withCredentials: true` in your example?

Comment: Hi Kyle, were you able to resolve the problem (pass credentials when doing a post?)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use HttpClient you have to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` instand of `HttpModule` and start inject `HttpClient` object instand of `http`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  };

  public myFunction(body) {
    let requestOptions = { withCredentials : true };
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:9090/api/values",body,requestOptions);
  }
}
```

> When you use HttpClient you don't need to do `.map(res => res.json())`

component

```
 constructor(myService: MyService) {
      this.myService = myService;
      this.myService.myFunction({username:'test',password:'123465'})
      .subscribe(data => console.warn(data), err => console.error(err),() => console.log("empty")
      );
   }
```

> Normaly you don't need to subscribe from your service so you can get
>   the data to the component

**ngOnInit**

> As a general good practice you have to do the initial api request in
>   ngOninit  method

[complete guide about http](https://angular.io/guide/http) , [RequestOptions](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

*Finaly this is typescript tip*

this is shorthand syntax

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  };
```

to this

```
private http: HttpClient;
 constructor(http: HttpClient) {
   this.http = http
  };
```

Comment: The component would be much cleaner if you write `constructor(private myService: MyService) {...}`
Than you can use `this.myService` everythere.

Comment: I wrote a tip about this at the end so he don't get confused  @DanielHabenicht

Comment: Thanks so much! One more question before I can get it working. You'll notice in my example I passed the `withCredentials: true` key/value pair to `myFunction` within the service. This is something I cannot do without, due to my API configuration. How can I include `withCredentials: true` in your example?

Comment: @KyleVassella I have update my answer and show you how set request options

Comment: Thanks again. I'm so close. But using your example, I'm now getting a `401 (Unauthorized)` error, and a `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401` like I was before I implemented my original `withCredentials: true`. The way I did it in my example works, but your example does not. :/ I've looked at other answers and they are similar to your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606752/angular-using-the-equivalent-of-requestoptions-of-http-with-httpclient
Any ideas?

Comment: the only deffrent in the example that I show how to send data with http post body
can you try like this     return `this.http.post("http://localhost:9090/api/values",null,requestOptions);` and this error related to your api you may check console network panel and see the post request and compare with the old one @KyleVassella Happy day

Comment: Using your example, if I use `null` for `body`, the request goes through with no error. Only when POST has data does the 401 error throw. If I change your example to use a `GET` request, it goes through with no error and I successfully retrieve the data from my API. So something about POSTing with Data is somehow not registering `withCredentials: true` - but other requests send those credentials along fine. If I set `withCredentials: false` on the GET request, it fails. If I set `withCredentials: true` on the GET request, it's successful. POST though, fails when including data.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the code for my `Web API controller`. Perhaps the problem lies there, where my POST endpoint is defined. Could you take a look at it? You'll see my POST takes a string and passes it to the `strings` List defined at the top. Perhaps this is not matching up with the data I'm sending from my Angular controller, which is an object with key value pairs: `this.acErrorService.postError({'test': 'testvalue'})` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine except for the service.
Also I have seen that your API have [Authorize]. You need to pass an authorization

ex:

```
const httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': myToken
 }),
 withCredentials: true
};
```

on your Http Request so that you wont get an Authorization Required error.

This reference might be useful: https://angular.io/guide/security

Service using HttpClient:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

 // api path
 const API_URL = 'http://10.111.1.23:80/api/my_api/api/yourController';

 // add http headers.
 const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   })
  };

 @Injectable()
 export class MyService {

 // inject the Http Client to the constructor
 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { };

 myFunction(entity: any): Observable<yourModel> {
    // using http client the return value of you api is
    // directly map to your model
    return this._http.post<yourModel>(API_URL ,
      entity, httpOptions);
 );
}
```

Comment: The `Authorization` part is where I'm so stuck. No matter what I try, I still get an `OPTIONS 401 (unauthorized)` error when `POST`ing data. I've enabled cors, etc. **My `Web API` is currently using `Windows Authentication`. I believe this may be what the `[Authorize]` attribute ties into. What could I even pass as the value for `'Authorization': mytoken`? What would go in place of `mytoken`?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: myToken is a variable containing jwt token (see jwt.io) in my case I store my token on a localStorage and then retrieve it and store it into myToken variable then attach it to my authorization header.