# Angular HttpClient replacement for RequestOptions?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Angular's `Http` module used to have a `RequestOptions` object which could be passed to its `get` method (e.g. `this.http.get(fooUrl, barOptions)`. The `RequestOptions` contained any headers. This was [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations). The "closest replacement" for the deprecated `RequestOptions` is [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest).

There's two problems with this:
 1. `HttpRequest` has a `url` param, so it is NOT an equivalent of `RequestOptions`. In fact, it seems to encapsulate the entire request, yet I don't see it used anywhere, so I am guessing it's just an internal class..
 2. `HttpClient`'s `get` method does NOT take `HttpRequest` as an argument.

The source code for `HttpClient`'s `get` method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Constructs a `GET` request that interprets the body as an `ArrayBuffer` and returns the response in
 *  an `ArrayBuffer`.
 *
 * @param url     The endpoint URL.
 * @param options The HTTP options to send with the request.
 *
 * @return An `Observable` of the response, with the response body as an `ArrayBuffer`.
 */
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'arraybuffer';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<ArrayBuffer>;
```

Is s there some type I can use for the `options` param now? Should I just define an interface that has [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) on it? If there isn't a type for it, why not?

My old code looks like this:

```
reqOptions.headers.set('Authorization', user.token);
reqOptions.headers.set('RefreshToken', user.refreshToken);
```

`RequestOptions` from the old `Http` module had a headers property and was statically typed.

P.S. I read the answer here, but it doesn't use a type:
[Angular4: Http -> HttpClient - requestOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797513/angular4-http-httpclient-requestoptions)

Comment: which version of angular are you on/coming from?

Comment: Going from 7 to 8. I think this could apply to anyone updating from 4 or so iirc. We just never fully applied `HttpClient` across the board.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I just defined "my own" `RequestOptions` interface in a new file in my app called `request-options.ts`. The interface definition is below, the properties were lifted straight out of the Angular Library's `client.d.ts` file to match what `HttpClient` expects from the `options` param for REST calls:

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface RequestOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  params?: HttpParams;
}
```

Now I can statically type `RequestOptions` again, e.g.:

```
const requestOptions: RequestOptions = {
  params: new HttpParams()
};
```

(Above example code lifted from here: [Angular4: Http -> HttpClient - requestOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797513/angular4-http-httpclient-requestoptions))

I am not sure if I am completely missing something or I should go make a PR against the angular repo. This seems like a rather obvious omission if there isn't a reason for it.

Comment: ok, this is just one of the multiple type definition for RequestOptions, if you read the http.d.ts (@angular/common/http), and i don't think you are using the one with a responseType arraybuffer (only JSON in 2019 XD) , an idea may be to just craft your "partial" RequestOption for your use cases

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little something I had written as a helper service. I'm sure you could extend to pass along any explicit headers.

```js
export class ParamBuilderService {
  buildParams(queryParams: Params, excludedValues ? : Array < string > ): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    for (const key in queryParams) {
      if (queryParams.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = queryParams[key];
        if (excludedValues) {
          const containExcludedValue = excludedValues.indexOf(value) !== -1;
          if (!!value && !containExcludedValue) {
            params = params.append(key, value);
          }
        } else if (!!value || value === 0) {
          params = params.append(key, value);
        }
      }
    }
    return params;
  }
}
```